# Random Audio Playing - Unity3d

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, game-engine, unityscript

I don't know what is wrong with my script, at the moment I have a main menu music playing and this script is meant to overlap and evil laugh sound over the main menu music at a random time different every time.

```
    var soundToPlay : AudioSource;

function Start(){   

    Invoke("PlaySound", Random.Range(5.0, 20.0));

}


function PlaySound(){

    if (!soundToPlay.isPlaying)
        soundToPlay.Play();

    Invoke("PlaySound", Random.Range(5.0, 20.0));

}
```

I did set the audio source but I get this error (I think when the audio is going to play) not at build:

MissingMethodException Unity.AudioClip.Play

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: I tried the code it seems to work well for me.. maybe some other code is the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can play an AudioClip but not an AudioSource, try var soundToPlay : AudioClip;